# Ember Rails outlet not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

Outlet does not seem to be rendering at all some how in Rails

I've put this under my landing page like below which is in default root view

```
%script{ type: 'text/x-handlebars' }
    {{ outlet }}
```

So I tried putting in below under `outlet`

```
{{#linkTo 'users'}}Users{{/linkTo}}
```

And above link did appear.

Is there a reason why `outlet` is not appearing/rendering at all (even just the static html elements and texts from other template handlebars file)?

My users route is below:

**routes/users_route.js.coffee**

```
VirtualExhibition.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ->
        VirtualExhibition.User.find()
```

Below is Router file

**router.js.coffee**

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen
    namespace: 'api/v1'


VirtualExhibition.Router.map ()->
    @resource 'users', ->
        @route 'show'
```

**application.hbs**

```
application
{{ outlet }}
```

**users.hbs**

```
users
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: Do you have a users route?

Comment: @kingpin2k I just updated my answer with users route and other files. Please have a look.

Comment: Does the word application show up?

Comment: No it doesn't show up at all

Comment: @kingpin2k maybe it's because I'm using `hbs` extension?

Comment: Are you sure the application is starting?  Do the debug messages show up in the console?